# Profile Ad Hoc installation doesn't work, i don't see it when i download it

Tags: ios, react-native, ipad, profile, ipa

I want to install a react native app made in xCode on an ipad, but since it is the first time i really don't know what i did wrong and what should i do.

I created an ad Hoc profile linked to the app, created a certificate IOS Distribution for ad hoc and all, then i built my app to have the ipa file and put it on my ipad and downloader the profile on my ipad but when i download it, it opens the view for the profile but i don't see any

Can anyone help me !

I try to redownload it several time but it is not working and i know i can download profiles since i try to get the udid of my ipad on a website that downloads a profile.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We need to have more details to aid debugging, at least some config files, maybe some code too.